# Android- GridView resizing cell contents

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm trying to build a GridView where all cells have the same height, but it seems the GridView is applying a varying height to each cell. I set the layout_height to a fixed measure on the layout I inflate in the cells, and this is maintained if I just add it to a static activity. But when I try to inflate it in the cells, it seems to be resizing that layout to the minimum required space.

Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="295dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/row_book_back" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_image" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So I effectively have a header and footer, and an image that should be centered in the remaining space. What happens when I add it's drawn on a cell though, is that the space the image takes is resized down to fit the image height, rather than just centering the image, and the whole Layout ends up taking less than the specified 350dp.

I'm pretty new to Android, so this might be a trivial issue to fix. I appreciate any input :)

Comment: You can try setting minHeight. Or since you want to achieve fixed height, you could set height to the views inside your LinearLayout. Really depends on complexity of your relative layouts..

Answer (score 0):

When displaying items in a GridView, I'll wrap the entire grid item view in a fixed aspect FrameLayout.  I'd also wrap the ImageView in the same layout to fix the size of that as well.  I've been using it for video clips that need to be fixed to 16:9 or 4:3, your case may be different.  Adjust the aspect of the outer layout to suite the size of the header and footer.

I take no claim to this code, ran into it somewhere, but I did have to add the styled attributes so I can set the aspect in the xml.

```
public class FixedAspectFrame extends FrameLayout {

    public FixedAspectFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setStyledAttributes(context, attrs);        
        mContext = context;

    }

    private float mAspectRatio = 1.7777f;  // 16:9
    private Context mContext = null;

   private void setStyledAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FixedAspectFrame);
      mAspectRatio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.FixedAspectFrame_aspect, mAspectRatio);

      a.recycle();
   }

    @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

            int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int receivedWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int receivedHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            int measuredWidth;
            int measuredHeight;
            boolean widthDynamic;
            if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
              if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                widthDynamic = receivedWidth == 0;
              } else {
                widthDynamic = true;
              }
            } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
              widthDynamic = false;
            } else {
              super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
              return;
            }
            if (widthDynamic) {
              // Width is dynamic.
              int w = (int) (receivedHeight * mAspectRatio);
              measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
              measuredHeight = heightMeasureSpec;
            } else {
              // Height is dynamic.
              measuredWidth = widthMeasureSpec;
              int h = (int) (receivedWidth / mAspectRatio);
              measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            }
            super.onMeasure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        }
}
```